# How do I make it so pressing tab in $\frac{}{}$ goes from the numerator to the denominator in TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, texmaker, shortcut

I know that Texmaker had this feature, but I decided to switch to Texstudio and this is probably the only thing I miss about Texmaker. I would assume that having this feature in Texstudio is possible as Texstudio is a fork of Texmaker, but I am not sure how to get this feature to work. Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Options > Configure > Shortcuts. Then you can choose the key for *Next placeholder or one word right*.

[image]

**But** if you choose a very useful key (like `Tab`) you have to change its behavior also in the *Tab or indent selection* (because does not make sense to have two functions for the same key).

[image]

Comment: When I go to shortcuts, I see this: https://i.imgur.com/En2cPvz.png. What do I click to see the screen you are on?

Comment: Go to *Basic key map*

Comment: @MohammedShahid If Sigur's answer helps you, you should accept it by clicking the tick right below the vote buttons. Also, don't forget offering Sigur at the end of the bounty duration.

Comment: @JouleV my mistake. I forgot to give him the bounty right after the 24 hours. Thank you for the reminder.